# BeautifulSoup targeting a string between tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<li class="li_dataline2">


<b> Expiry date: </b>14/09/2013


</li>
```

Ok here's an easy one (I think!?) Can someone tell me how to extract the date? So everything between `</b> </li>` using BeautifulSoup?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.contents`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children)

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> html = """<li class="li_dataline2">
... 
... 
... <b> Expiry date: </b>14/09/2013
... 
... 
... </li>"""
>>> soup = BS(html)
>>> print soup.find('li', {'class':'li_dataline2'}).contents[-1].strip()
14/09/2013
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks Haidro.. that's definitely got me on the right track. Another quick question though! How would I find the "next instance" of those tags. What I mean is, there is another set of </b> </li> tags beneath that, and I want to get the data from that too. Does that make sense! Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @user2574810 You could use `find_all()` to find all the li tags, then loop through them and do what I've shown above to get the date from each

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks, huge help.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> s
'<li class="li_dataline2">\n\n\n<b> Expiry date: </b>14/09/2013\n\n\n</li>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> soup.find('li', attrs={'class': 'li_dataline2'}).b.nextSibling.strip()
u'14/09/2013'
```

You can just use `re` too:

```
>>> p = re.compile('<b> Expiry date: </b>([\d/]+)\s*</li>')
>>> p.search(s).group(1)
'14/09/2013'
>>>
```

Comment: Ahh interesting, thanks very much this is helpful too for another string I want to get. Thanks for your time!